# Generate a POST request and send the json data via API

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to integrate my PHP script with an API towards Market Hero email system.

Their API instructions says:

> Generate a POST request to this url:
>   //api.markethero.io/v1/api/tag-lead and send the json data.

The data should look like:

```
{
 "apiKey":"38883ca614e36881995a16a54a060d4309870143acd40203832d3260b65deaa9",
 "firstName":"John",
 "lastName":"Doe",
 "email":"john.doe@mail.com",
 "tags":["Tag1", "Tag2"]
}
```

I have tried to search and use API-examples found both here and via Google, but to no avail yet.

I have tested with this (got the code from [here](http://thisinterestsme.com/sending-json-via-post-php/)):

```
<?php

//API Url
$url = '//api.markethero.io/v1/api/tag-lead';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
'apiKey' => 'myapikeyhere',
'firstName' => 'Test',
'lastName' => 'Tester',
'email' => 'some@mailinator.com',
'tags' => 'Tag2'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
echo '1';
//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
echo '2';
//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
echo '3';
//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
echo '4';
//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'Done';
?>
```

The echo 1,2,3,4 etc are just to get a glimpse of where the execution stops. But it goes all the way to "Done".

What do I do wrong?

The Market Hero is new, and their devs have too much on their shoulders to help me with this right now, and I understand that. I hope some of you might be able to help me with this.

PS: I have also tried this as the JSON data for adding multiple tags.

```
//The JSON data.
    $jsonData = array(
    'apiKey' => 'myapikeyhere',
    'firstName' => 'Test',
    'lastName' => 'Tester',
    'email' => 'some@mailinator.com',
     tags =>array("tag1", "tag2")
    );
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the protocol in the URL? Something like "http" or "https" ? I tested here with "http" in Fiddler and the API returned this JSON to me: {"errors":{"error":"invalid_api_key"}}

Comment: You are kidding me. All in all I have tested a lot, and that was the last drop. It works... :-)